# iterate over Result returned from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I could not able to iterate through Result returned from mongodb

Here is code that connect to mongodb and gets the result

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {       

        var collection = db.collection('users');            

            collection.remove({}, { w: 1 }, function (err, result) {
                    console.log(result.ok);
                    res.json    ({ success: true, obj:result.ok});                    
            })
});
```

the result is

```
obj: {ok: 1,n: 0}
```

I am getting undefined when i tried to access the value of **n** using **result.n**.

Could anyone let me know the way to access the values of returned result in nodejs

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't. The result of:

```
res.json({ "success": true, "obj": result })
```

is

```
{ "success": true, "obj": { "ok": 1, "n": 0 } }
```

and not what you claim as that is how the object serializes to JSON and how you are accessing it.

However the "true" object returned has itself it's own `result` key, so if you want to access the `n` property or even the `ok` property then you instead must do this:

```
console.log(result.result.n);
```

And here is the simple listing that proves this:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/test",function(err,db) {

  var collection = db.collection('testme');

  async.series(
    [
      function(callback) {
        collection.remove({},callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        collection.insert(
          [
            { "data": 1 },
            { "data": 2 }
          ],
          callback
        );
      },
      function(callback) {
        collection.remove({},function(err,result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result.result.n));
          callback(err);
        });
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      db.close();
    }
  );

});
```

With expected results:

```
{"ok":1,"n":2}
2
```

This is because what is "actually" returned is a [`deleteWriteOpResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#~deleteWriteOpResult) object from the node native driver API and not a plain object. The accessor method is really what you need.

The [`.remove()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#remove) method is also considered deprecated in the API and the preference is to use [`.deleteMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#deleteMany) instead. They both in fact do the same thing, but the deprecation notice means your code should be using that method for future compatibility:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongodb = require('mongodb'),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/test",function(err,db) {

  var collection = db.collection('testme');

  async.series(
    [
      function(callback) {
        collection.deleteMany({},callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        collection.insert(
          [
            { "data": 1 },
            { "data": 2 }
          ],
          callback
        );
      },
      function(callback) {
        collection.deleteMany({},function(err,result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result.result.n));
          callback(err);
        });
      }
    ],
    function(err) {
      db.close();
    }
  );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to mongodb's docs - [`db.collection.remove()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/)

`.remove` should returns a `WriteResult` object that looks like `WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })`. In case of error, it should return:

```
WriteResult({
   "nRemoved" : 21,
   "writeConcernError" : {
      "code" : 64,
      "errInfo" : {
         "wtimeout" : true
      },
      "errmsg" : "waiting for replication timed out"
   }
})
```